# Can anyone ID this oak that has flaky bark?

Tags: identification, trees, oak

This is on Long Island, NY near the water. No acorns are available.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is White Oak or Quercus alba. Typical features are the yellow main veins in the leaves, the rounded tips to the leaf lobes, the height and solidity of the tree. In [this description from Georgia Native Plant Society](https://gnps.org/plants/white-oak-quercus-alba/) note the reference to "shaggy" bark which is not always present, almost like a Shagbark Hickory. Distinctive other features are that the leaves turn red in the fall, and compare the upper and lower surfaces of the leaves to the various descriptions available. The wood of white oak is quite valuable due to its hardness. Don't just give it away when it finally retires, and it is worth looking after.

Comment: If it weren't for the shaggy bark I'd have thought white oak. The property is covered in white oaks, but non have this characteristic.